# Printing the different values in a column not the amount of their repeats

Tags: python

```
Dust: Fe
Dust: Fe
Dust: Fe
Dust: Al203
Dust: Al203    
Dust: Fe
Dust: Fe
Dust: Fe
```

Say I have the above columns which can be hundreds (maybe higher) of rows deep. What would be the easiest way to search for the different values in the second column (python: [i][1] column) and only print the values that occur not print all the times they occur?

So for example, I would like the output to just be: Fe Al203

I don't know how to do that, without printing every occurrence.

Thanks.

Comment: You can build a `set`?

Comment: Use a `set` to keep track of the values you have printed.  Or you could use a dictionary, but a set is preferred.

Comment: `set` or a `dict`.  Learn python datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would look something like:

```
uniquevalues = {row.value for row in rows}
```

How you get the list of values is another matter. For example, if `rows` are the lines in a file, that might be like:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as infile:
    uniquevalues = {row.split(': ')[1] for row in infile}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set`, like this:

```
>>> s = "Dust: Fe"
>>> t = "Dust: Al203"
>>> lines = [s, s, s, t, t, s, s, s]
>>> set(s[6:] for s in lines)
set(['Al203', 'Fe'])
```